# One second session time out in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-boot, session-timeout

I configured the application.properties to have a one second session time out.
*(I was just doing this to test session time out in my application. The real application will have a much longer session)*

```
server.session.timeout=1
server.session.tracking-modes=cookie
```

In the browser, i refreshed the page every 5 seconds to see if JSESSIONID is changing. But looks like it isn't.

[image]

Although, I tried refreshing after a while, the  JSESSIONID changed.

Is there a minimum session time out in spring boot?

Comment: as i remember http session timeouts should be declared in minutes not seconds. try check sessions renew with more interval

Comment: @ivanenok http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html says, `server.session.timeout= # Session timeout in seconds.`

Answer (score 1):

`server.session.timeout` works only in case of `embedded` tomcat container and not in case of `Standalone`.

If you want to set it , you have to configure it in web.xml

something like below:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

so in this case, session timeout will be set to 1 min

Comment: I am using the embedded server